# Добавление данных из ComboBox в БД

Tags: база-данных, delphi

Как реализовать, чтобы при выборе определенного item'a из combobox'a он записывался в опредеденное поле в БД?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще что-нибудь типа `DBLookupComboBox` использовать. У этого компонента свойства `Datasource` и `Listsource`. `Datasource` - результат твоей основной выборки (и свойство `Datafield` - поле, которое ты менять собираешься), а `Listsource` - то, что в выпадающем списке будет показано (и свойство `KeyField` - поле, значение которого ты будешь записывать в БД).